# Einstein summation and square roots

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation

It has occurred to me I don't know if there is a general rule about this or not.

If I have an expression like:

$$\int \sqrt{g_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt}} dt$$

I take the summation *inside* the square root (i.e. before performing the square root).

But is this a general rule ?  If I see $\sqrt{a_{ij}}$ am I *always* supposed to assume the summation is done before the square root or is this very context dependent ?

Comment: $\sqrt{a_{ij}}$ doesn’t have a summation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner expression reads:

$$ g_{ij} \frac{dx^i}{dt} \frac{dx^j}{dt} =  \sum_{\text{all}(i,j)}  g_{ij} \frac{dx^i}{dt} \frac{dx^j}{dt} $$

So you'd have to sum and then square root as the sum and square root operations are not interchangeable

Comment: The question is if this is a general rule when you see a square root in tensor calculus.

Comment: I mean disregard it being a rule, the definition of it is to do a double sum if you have repeated indices. Now, you can't interchange double sums with a square root and hence you have to do the sum first

Comment: So you are saying use the context of the indices to work out what summation is required in general.  So if related upper and lower indices occur inside the square root we have to take the square root after the summation ?  But what if there are no related indices to imply a summation ?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you call it in your tensor course but in the book that I did if an indice appears on both sides it is known as a live index. If you have a live index, then you'd put in the same value of live indices on both sides and then you'd evaluate the sum. In this particular example, there are only contracted indices ( repeating ones)

Comment: So if there weren't any repeating indice, then we'd have to evaluate both side at some value of live index. I highly highly highly recommend that you get Pavel Grinfield's book on tensor calculus because he has one of the best explanations on this topic